# Removing a duplicate element from a JSON Array

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, json, array

I'm trying to figure out a way to dedupe JSON arrays based on the _prop.Invoice_Number__c value returned by a Remote Object retrieve. Please see attached screenshot of the JSON as viewed through a JSON editor to see the structure of the array.

I played around with lodash _uniq but with no success. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where is this JSON array? Apex or JavaScript?

Comment: Unique... how? Those are different line items on the same invoice, it appears. I don't see how that's not unique already.

Comment: @Bachovski - JavaScript

Comment: @sfdcfox Correct - I'm trying to build a expandable datatable with the invoice header information for the primary rows that can be expanded to item information. I could normalize the source data and leverage separate objects and build out the table that way but having encountered this situation with the denormalized data I am interested in how one would approach parsing out the JSON data. Thanks.

Comment: @vshake I see what you're going for... Technically, I don't see anything wrong with `var output = {}; input.forEach(function(e,i,a) { output[e._props.Invoice_Number__c] = output[e._props.Invoice_Number__c] || []; output[e._props.Invoice_Number__c].push(e); });` There's a way to use _.uniq in the same way, but I'm not familiar with lodash (although, now that you've mentioned it, I'll probably learn it).

Comment: Almost there! Original stringified output sample start of record:  {"_name":"Invoice_Item__c","_fields":{"Ship_To_Amount__c":      post processing stringified output sample start of record:  {"65489":[{"_name":"Invoice_Item__c","_fields":{"Ship_To_Amount__c":   My data table can read the _props of the first but not the second - it looks like we need to strip off the encompassing {"<Invoice Number>: }

Comment: Looks like I'll need to create a class that I can deserialize the JSON into as a list of objects then map and remove dupes based on Invoice_Number__c key and reserialize before feeding into the datatable.